# Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field with a characteristic $P$, prove that if $P\neq{0}$, then $m$ is a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. Let's define a characteristic $P$ of $\Bbb{K}$ like this:

1. If $\sum_{i=1}^m 1\neq{0}$, then $P=0$
2. If $\sum_{i=1}^m 1={0}$ for some $m\geq{2}$ then $P$ is the lowest number $m$ with this property.

Now I'm asked to prove this two statements:

1. Show that if $P\neq{0}$, then $m$ is a prime number.
2. Show fields with characteristics equal to $0$, and others with chacteristics different from $0$.

but to be really honest, I'm not understanding this *characteristic* thing. So, right now it's kind of impossible for me to tackle the proofs if I'm not even understanding the definitions yet. I'm new to Linear Algebra but we are using some concepts of Abstract Algebra to enrich our classes.

I hope someone can explain me this and if you can, much appreciated! By the way, the book is in Portuguese (I don't know Portuguese), so the definitions/questions are a rough translation of what I grasped from the book.

I want to make clear that I'm not looking for a proof, I'm looking for an explanation so I can prove it myself.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! The type of questions that get most answers here are specific, and show some basic knowledge of the material. Your type of question will usually get downvoted and utlitmately closed, because it asks for a little bit too much, and shows zero knowledge. If you don't understand the *characteristic* thing, read again your textbook, look up examples, search the web, and then come back.

Comment: I'm okay with the question.  He's asking for help understanding and gaining some intuition for the concept of characteristic.  That seems like a perfectly appropriate use of the site.  I think once he's developed some understanding of the concept he'll be able to tackle the problem.

Comment: My textbook is Um Curso de Álgebra Linear by Flávio Ulhoa Coehlo, the question is from the first section (Preliminaries) where it involves complex numbers, fields and linear equations systems. We are only grasping what a field is, and I've been able to prove the whole section of Fields but this last point that sadly I am unable to understand. I know what a Field is and it's definitions but to be honest I don't see the correlation between a field K and the characteristics. It seems unnatural for me that a in a field 1+1+...+1=0, at least when trying to visualize it in fields like R.

Comment: One family of examples of fields with non-zero characteristic is arithmetic modulo $p$ on $\{0,1,...,p-1\},$ where $p$ is any prime number.

Answer (score 1):

First, the definition you're using is slightly too complex.  The characteristic of a field is the smallest $p$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^p 1 = 0$.  If that never happens, the field's characteristic is $0$.

Most fields that you're probably familiar with have characteristic $0$.  I'll get you started with an example of a field that has characteristic $2$.  Let $F=\{0, 1\}$ and define the field operations using arithmetic modulo $2$.  Thus, for example, $1+1=0$ (because $2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$).  I'll leave it to you to prove that $F$ defined with these operations really is a field.

Notice that if a field $F$ has characteristic $p$, then $\forall x \in F~\sum_{i=1}^p x=\sum_{i=1}^p 1 \cdot x = (\sum_{i=1}^p 1)x=0 \cdot x =0$.

This example may give you a hint to help you come up with other fields with non-zero characteristic.  The key fact you need to remember about fields is that they have no zero divisors.  That's how you prove that if a field has non-zero characteristic $p$, then $p$ must be prime.

Comment: Oh! Now everything clicks. In the textbook there was an example of finite fields like this but I didn't think of defining K in a different way. Thank you very much!